# removing multibyte characters from a file using sed

Tags: sed, multibyte

i need to remove all multibyte characters from a file, i dont know what they are so i need to cover the whole range.

I can find them using grep like so:
grep -P "[\x80-\xFF]" 'myfile'

Trying to do a simular thing with sed, but delete them instead.

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
LANG=C sed 's/[\x80-\xFF]//g' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [iconv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv) to convert from one encoding to another